# Do we need the CE certification for test series in quantity of 100pcs

Tags: documentation, certification, ce, regulations

We are developing a multimedia application WiFi + Audio out + Mic Input + and few buttons), which we plan to produce in the number of 100 pieces and half of that sell to our aquaintances and the rest from site bu using pre-order mechanism button.
In this way we could geather feedback about the device and then re-think is there is future for such device and if there is sence to produce it in bigger series
So the question is: 
How can we bypass the CE certification as there is no need in it for a small series.
We would like to know how would be correct law-wise or maybe in somehow through the agreement state this point and aknowledge the customers
about such approach? Has this been practiced by anyone before and is this possible theoretically?

Originally all the components( WiFi module etc) inside the device are certified, incoming parameter are: input voltage  5V, current consumption 800mA, charger is not included.

Comment: Im not 100% sure but sticking a sticker with a text "Engineering Sample" and not charging any money for the product might do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bypassing CE might not be a good idea but you can self-certify and place the CE mark on your product. Self certifying means you do your own testing and document results. If you believe certain tests can be avoided because you are not infringing how a certain module is recommended to be used then that is acceptable.

Low voltage directive and EMC directive are the obvious hurdles but with a little thought and research you should be fine given what you've said about the product you are building.

Alternatively don't mark with the CE symbol and don't make any claims about it. Buyer beware etc.

[Here](https://www.gov.uk/ce-marking) is the UK's government site that is fairly clear on the subject. [Here](http://www.newapproach.org/Directives/DirectiveList.asp) is the list of directives that may or may not apply to your product - if you click on the "info" column against the relevant directive, more information pops-up.

Comment: Including a radio module makes it "radio and telecommunications equipment", which is in the "must be CE marked" category? I'm still unclear under what circumstances you can self-certify.

Comment: @pjc50 If the RF module (already bearing its own CE mark) is intended to be used in the application to which they wish to use it and they follow the recommendations then I don't see that it needs to have full-blown radio tests. What would be the point in CE marking a wifi module if it couldn't be "incorporated" into another piece of equipment. This might help http://www.conformance.co.uk/cemarking/basics.php

Comment: For example we are planning to use such WiFi module TI CC3000, because this module already has all kinds of certification. Can this fact become an argument?

Comment: All kinds of certification? This could mean anything. The CE problem for your product does rest with the RF module and its legality to be sold and used in the market you intend to sell to.

Comment: I just mean this module http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC3000_Product_Certification and it look likes that this RF module has not only CE certification

Comment: @Andyaka if you have a reference that _explicitly_ says that it's OK to use a CE module in a device without further testing I'd be very keen to see it. But everything I've seen refers to the _device as a whole_.

Comment: (also, you need to clarify what you mean by "full blown radio tests": do you need ETSI 389-401 or not?

Comment: @Pianist If you can find the CE declaration of conformity of the CC3000 then that's a big step on the way - there was a broken link on the ti page in your comment. You might also be looking for a CE declaration of incorporation.

Comment: @pjc50 - the link provided by Pianist to the TI site clearly says it is CE marked (and usable without going thru expensive radio re-testing) but to be able to use it legally you need a declaration of conformity or declaration of incorporation.

Comment: "Declaration of incorporation only exists within the Machinery directive" http://www.conformance.co.uk/info/declarationofinc.php; and that link from Pianist says "Warning: EMC testing obligations may still be required as determined by the specific end product requirements. " and "Note that some countries do not recognize modular approval."; it's still not entirely clear to me, especially if the host device needs to undergo EMC testing.

Comment: (This isn't just pedantry, I'm in a similar situation with a modular product and very frustrated by the complexity of the legal requirements)

Comment: @pjc50 I didn't think it was pedantry dude. Any advice I can give is not a problem. I've sailed a little close on a couple of products where I've used FM modulation but ensured, by tests/measurements I wasn't transmitting EM waves (only magnetism like in a transformer and limited in power). I had to think hard and do a fair bit of research to justify self-certification but I'm sure I was on the correct side of legality (given the application). Read the links - this might help and there are flow charts to follow somewhere.

Comment: CE declaration of conformity of the CC3000 =  http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/swrq004/swrq004.pdf